# Convert code of Matlab to Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I make one code in matlab to resolve and plot one diferential equation, but my problem now is how to make in simulink:

The code of matlab is:

```
function dy = eqdif1(t,y)

%y''+4y=sin^2(2x)

% with initial values y(pi) = 0,y’(pi) = 0
% y(1)=y  y(2)=y'

dy = [y(2); (sin(2*t).^2 - 4*y(1))];

clc,clear

yp = [0 0];  %initial values
options = odeset('RelTol', 1e-4);

[t,y]= ode23('eqdif1',[pi pi*3],yp,options); 

ya=-(1/6)*cos(2.*t)+ (1/4)*(cos(2.*t)).^2-(1/12)*(cos(2.*t)).^4+ (1/12)*(sin(2.*t)).^4; %analitical solution
 figure
 plot(t,y(:,1),'-',t,y(:,2),'--',t,ya,'-.')
 title(['y'''' + 4y = sin^2(2x)'])
```

Anybody can help me, with one example or explication of simulink

Thank you

Comment: If you search for "matlab code in simulink" you will get many results. Were they not helpful?

Comment: No i did not saw, nothing  interesting for my example. Now I saw some examples but i no understand.

Comment: x0=[2.5;0];
tf=3*pi;
options=simset('InitialState',x0);
[t,x]=sim('vdp2n',tf,options);                                                                                                                                                                
plot(t,x(:,1),'-',t,x(:,2),'-.')
With the example van der pool equation, works correctly, but in my case pass x0=[0,0], and no work, for this reson, maybe no understand nothing or no correctly  @Navan

Answer (score 0):

you can use MATLAB Function block in Simulink and copy your code into the function. But it important you add a line define all the matlab commands in the first line of your function:

```
coder.extrinsic('odeset','ode23', 'figure','plot','title')
```

you might also nee to add end at the bottom of the function.

Matlab Function Block Link: [http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html?refresh=true)
coder.extrinsic documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/coder.extrinsic.html

Or Hirshfeld

אור הירשפלד

Comment: There is also option to slove it using special simulink block for solving differential equations, it called DEE. follow this link: http://www.ualberta.ca/~fforbes/che572/pdf_current/DEE_tutorial.pdf

Comment: As of R2014b, `odeset` and `ode23` are [supported for code generation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/release-notes.html#R2014b) so you shouldn't need to declare them as extrinsic